# Kernel32 CreateFile not giving exclusive access to USB device

Tags: c#, usb, createfile, kernel32

I am taking what was traditionally a single-instance-only application and updating it so multiple instances can execute on the same PC.  Each instance will require exclusive access to a USB device.  The first application instance opens a USB device with the following command (some Kernel32 wrappers for C# are in place) and gets a valid handle, as expected:

```
 this.handle = Kernel32.CreateFile(
       pathToUsbDevice,
       Convert.ToUInt32(FileRead.Read | FileRead.Write),
       Convert.ToUInt32(FileShare.None),
       IntPtr.Zero,
       Convert.ToUInt32(CreateDisposition.OpenExisting),
       Convert.ToUInt32(FileFlags.Overlapped),
       IntPtr.Zero);
```

The problem is that I then open the second instance of the application and it is able to also get a valid handle to the same device (while the first instance still has its handle).  This seems incorrect to me, as my understanding of `CreateFile` is that it should return an invalid file handle if that device is already opened exclusively (sharing set to 0, or None).

Am I doing something wrong in `CreateFile`?  Perhaps my assumption that it will return an invalid handle if the device is already exclusively opened is incorrect?  How can I exclusively open the device for a single application instance so that other application instances cannot open it?

In case it matters, the development & test PC is Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit, building the app via Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: What happens if you open file for synchronous I/O (i.e. without Overlapped flag)?

Comment: Just tried upon your suggestion.  Still seeing the same issue.  (I think it has to be opened Overlapped, but figured I'd give it a shot anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a device driver issue. I've found a [similar discussion](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=216850):

> It's up to the driver to manage shared/non-shared, not the IO manager.  So you 
>   have two choices:
>
> 1. Mark your device exclusive in the INF (see the Exclusive registry value under 
>      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546320(v=3Dvs.85).aspx
>      )
> 2. Add file create/close handlers in your driver and manage the count of clients 
>      yourself

You might want to use some other approach to ensure only one instance of your app is accessing device (like using a named global mutex to guard device access).

Comment: Updating the INF to add the following seems to have done the trick:
HKR,,Exclusive,0x10001,1
Thanks!